# xrandr settings and XQuartz In Multi-monitor Yosemite Environment

Tags: macos, display, x11

I am currently struggling with an inability to move Xquartz (either latest stable or latest development) windows in the top third or so of my screen, as also [described](https://superuser.com/questions/844291/x11-window-doesnt-take-up-whole-screen-in-os-x-yosemite) by another user.

My current solution is to manually set the resolution of the Xquartz display (not an Xwindows expert, apologies for any inaccurate language) in xterm:

`xrandr --output default --mode 3360x1080`

Which gives me freedom of movement to the top of both my screens.  However this is at the cost of all Xwindows disappearing when I switch “focus” to another application: obviously undesirable if I wish to reference my current work in an X environment, from another application.

Is anyone aware of a way to enable full screen movement a la my provisional `xrandr` workaround without losing the ability to view Xwindows while working in other applications?  Should I tweak the xrandr command/mix in any other settings?